# Проблемы с запросом к бд в yii2

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, yii

создал мультиязычное меню, все работает но есть одно но запроси к бд свище 20 для одного меню. Можете подсказать как оптимизировать это. Вот моя модель Menu

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Menu extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'menu';
    }

    /*public function relations()
    {
        return [
            'lang_menu' => [self::HAS_ONE, 'LangMenu', ['menu_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }*/

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['alias'], 'required'],
            [['alias'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['alias'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'alias' => Yii::t('app', 'Alias'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getLangMenu()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LangMenu::className(), ['menu_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /*
     * Возвращает массив объектов модели menu
     */
    public function getMenus($position){
        return $this->find()->indexBy('id')->with('langMenu')->where(['position' => $position])->all();
    }
    /*
     * Возвращает данные для указанного языка
     */
    public function getDataMenu(){
        $language = Yii::$app->language;
        $data_lang = $this->getLangMenu()->where(['lang'=>$language])->one();
        return $data_lang;
    }
}
```

Виджет

```
<?php

namespace frontend\components;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Widget;
use frontend\models\Menu;
use frontend\models\LangMenu;

class MenuWidget extends Widget
{

    public $tpl;
    public $position;
    public $model;
    public $data;
    public $nav;
    public $menuHtml;
    public $pages;  

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        if($this->tpl === null) {
            $this->tpl = 'menu';
        }
        if ($this->position === null) {
            $this->position = 'nav';
        }
        $this->tpl .= '.php';
    }



    public function run() {
        //  get cache
        if($this->tpl == 'menu.php') {
        $menu = Yii::$app->cache->get('menu');
        if($menu) return $menu;
        }
        //$this->tpl .= '.php';
        $this->pages = new Menu;
        $this->data = $this->pages->getMenus($this->position);

        $menu = [];

        foreach($this->data as $value) {
            $nav = $value->getDataMenu(); 
            $menu[$value->id]['id'] = $value->id;
            $menu[$value->id]['title'] = $nav->title;
            $menu[$value->id]['alias'] = $value->alias;
            $menu[$value->id]['parent_id'] = $value->parent_id;
            $menu[$value->id]['position'] = $value->position;
            $menu[$value->id]['status'] = $value->status;
        }

        $this->data = $menu;
        $this->nav = $this->getTree();
        $this->menuHtml = $this->getMenuHtml($this->nav);
        //debug($this->menuHtml);
        //  set cache
        if($this->tpl == 'menu.php') Yii::$app->cache->set('menu', $this->menuHtml, 600);
        return $this->menuHtml;
    }

    protected function getTree() {
        $tree = [];
        foreach ($this->data as $id=>&$node) {
            if (!$node['parent_id']) {
                $tree[$id] = &$node;
            } else {
                $this->data[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$node['id']] = &$node;
            }
        }
        return $tree;
    }

    protected function getMenuHtml($tree, $tab = '') {
        $str = '';
        foreach ($tree as $nav) {
            $str .= $this->catToTemplate($nav, $tab);
        }
        return $str;
    }

    protected function getMenu($tree, $tpl = "root.php") {
        $str = '';
        foreach ($tree as $nav) {
            $str .= $this->setToTemplate($nav, $tpl);
        }
        return $str;
    }

    protected function setToTemplate($nav, $tpl) {
        ob_start();
        include __DIR__.'/menu_tpl/'.$tpl;

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    protected function catToTemplate($nav, $tab) {
        ob_start();
        include __DIR__.'/menu_tpl/'.$this->tpl;

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: на какой странице много запросов? покажите код экшена контроллера данной страницы.

Comment: добавляйте код в вопрос, под меткой `upd` или типа того

Comment: Сделал, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: вы добавили виджет, а нужен контроллер, который делает запрос к модели и передает данные виджету, а т.к. модель у вас почти голая, смею предположить, что у вам много запросов именно в контроллере. добавьте код контроллера

Comment: Проблема в том что у меня нет контроллера

Comment: где тогда вы оформляете запросы? запросы вида `$model = new Model();` или `$model = Model::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();`? в `view`? в приведенных вами примерах кода я наблюдаю всего 1 запрос.

Comment: а вообще советую вам почитать про mvc, ведь в yii2 используется именно этот шаблон архитектуры